# Can I call method from wsdl?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2code

Is it possible to call method from wsdl.if yes how it can be achieved.Can i get web service name from wsdl?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wsdl` *describes* a web service - it is normally used to generate proxy classes that will allow you to call a service.

You should add a web reference to your project and point it to the `wsdl` file. Visual Studio will generate the proxy classes with appropriate namespace, which will allow you to use the web service.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I done with this.One proxy class get generated.Can you tell me how can i pass credentials info to that service in program,as proxy class generate by these credentials in my solution.

Comment: @RajaramShelar -  Take a look at the documentation for [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx). This is the tool that Visual Studio uses to generate the proxy classes. It has a `username` option for those occasions that you need to authenticate.

Comment: Can you please tell where i can get those options.I have one file reference.vb

Comment: @RajaramShelar - Not entirely sure what you are asking here. `wsdl.exe` is a command line tool and the documentation is about the command line options.

Comment: @Oded- Actually proxy class get generated when i add wsdl in solution.and its can not be modified.So is there need to regenerate proxy by giving username and password from wsdl.exe tool? Can get idea from following steps. 

**Solution Explorer->Add web reference->Add wsdl path->put username/password in pop up->proxy class(reference.vb) generated.**